# Memory error: multiplying large matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, out-of-memory, matrix-multiplication

A, B, C, and D are 361x361x120 double matrices.
I get an out of memory error when I try to perform the following calculation:

```
Result = (A.*B)+(C.*D);
```

Unfortunately, these must be in double and I need the following result for the rest of my calculations. I've tried separating the addition step but it gets stuck on the first multiplication (A*.B). Is there some way to break down these steps further to avoid the memory issue?

Thank you!

-N.

Comment: please add the proper language tag.

Comment: Maybe swap space is actually what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are doing an element by element multiplication you can simply split up the operation using loops. Here is an example of how to multiply A and B and save the result to a matrix C:

```
A = rand(361, 361, 120);
B = rand(361, 361, 120);
C = nan(361,361,120);

for i = 1:size(A,1);
  for j = 1:size(A,2);
     C(i,j,:) = A(i,j,:) .* B(i,j,:);
  end
end
```

You should be able to get it to work with a single loop instead of the two nested loops.

I'm not sure why you're getting an out of memory error though as the following executes fine on my machine. Additionally the multiplication shouldn't require much memory.

```
A = rand(361, 361, 120);
B = rand(361, 361, 120);
C = rand(361, 361, 120);
D = rand(361, 361, 120);

E = (A.*B) + (C.*D);
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great. This does however cause a problem further in my code only if the dimensions are above a certain threshold. I have wondered about the memory issue as well. These are my stats: Maximum possible array:             651 MB (6.826e+08 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:   1215 MB (1.274e+09 bytes) **
Memory used by MATLAB:              588 MB (6.161e+08 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):             5940 MB (6.228e+09 bytes)

Comment: Ah, the problem is I have a number of other variables saved in the workspace (all of which I need) which apparently pushes it over the threshold.

Comment: Each of your `361x361x120` variables is 120 MB of ram.  So having `A,B,C,D,E` all in memory is taking up nearly 600 MB.  Look at your code and figure out when you no longer need a variable and delete it, or buy more RAM.

Comment: So I was able to solve this alternatively using the following code: A = rand(361,361,120); B = rand(361,361,120); R1 = A.*B; clear A B; C = rand(361,361,120); D = rand(361,361,120); R2 = C.*D; clear C D; E = R1+R2; clear R1 R2; I am still having the problem later in my code however, but I will look into it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that each of your `A`,`B`,`C`, and `D` matrices require: `361*361*120*8` bytes (or `119` MB) of **contiguous memory**. When you execute `Result = (A.*B)+(C.*D);`, each of the two intermediate results and the final result will also require the same amount of memory (although the intermediate results are immediately released afterwards). At the peak, it would require space for 6 to 7 contiguous blocks of memory of size 119MB each.. (keep in mind how *fragmentation* affects the size of the maximum possible allocated matrix at any point in time)

If you don't have enough memory to hold all the above, rewrite the expression to reuse existing variables and `clear` no longer needed ones as soon as possible.

Otherwise, don't load/store all the data at once in memory. New versions of MATLAB allows you to load/save parts of MAT-files using the new `matfile` function. You would calculate the result in blocks with for-loops.

Other ideas: think about using sparse matrices if your data contains a lot of zeros. Also do you really need double-precision, you could halve the memory needed by using `single` types instead.

Of course, you could always move to a 64-bit machine with a matching MATLAB installation, and buy as much RAM as you can afford :)

Answer (score 0):

Your command seems to be equivalent to this:

```
 C = nan(361,361,120);
    for i = 1:361;
      for j = 1:361;
         C(i,j,:) = rand(120,1) .* rand(120,1);
      end
    end
```

Except this command uses substantially less memory